# dateFormat datepicker when using back button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, back-button

I have a datepicker on which I set a dateFormat of 'dd M yyyy'. This works fine on the initial load but when the user navigates to a different page and then clicks the back button to return the text box is left empty. If I remove the "dateFormat" the text box is repopulated when the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I faced the same problem. This worked for me:

```
//Suppose your control has the id 'txtDate'
var temp = $('#txtDate').val();
$('#txtDate').datepicker();
$('#txtDate').datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd M yyyy" );
$('#txtDate').val(temp);
```

Before applying the `datepicker` to the control, take a copy of its value and later re-assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have faced that issue. It will work for you.

```
// Text box id is 'txtSearch'
$("#txtSearch").datepicker("destroy");
$("#txtSearch").datepicker();
```

Please refers to this [link](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/253).